# jquery not working in html5 doc

Tags: jquery, html

I was watching a vidoe from lynda.com on how to make a scrolling marquee and I used the code in a HTML5 page and it does not work. So far the only problem I can find is that with a HTML4 there is in the  tag
html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
With out this the for some reason it will not work.
Does any one know why?

Comment: and also what connection to jquery? not mentioned in the question

Comment: Show some code and accept past answers, please. Also, the doctype for HTML5 is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`, nothing more. However, this will not affect jQuery in anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Well, after taking a look at one of the first ["training videos"](http://www.lynda.com/Dreamweaver-CS3-tutorials/Create-an-Interactive-Homepage-Marquee-with-jQuery-and-Dreamweaver/80445-2.html), I would strongly suggest to stop using that site for learning purposes.

It's like a collection of all the worst practices, available at single locations.

If you want to learn Javascript, you should instead avoid use of frameworks for now, and concentrate on learning the basics. Few links you might find useful:

- you should begin by watching **[Douglas Crockford: The JavaScript Programming Language](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M)**, it is an almost 2 hour long lecture in 4 parts, which will cover the basics you need to know.
- **http://eloquentjavascript.net/** : online (and free) book about Javascript, covering all the major things you must know
- **http://yuiblog.com/crockford/** : this page contains lectures about javascript. You could say that that they are organized in university style. There is the history, then some basics.  Then off to the deep end. At first you will have trouble understanding most of the advanced stuff. thats normal.
- **http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/** : collection of advices and things-you-should know for people who are new to Javascript.

When you are done with all of this, then take a look at jQuery. It will give you a solid understanding, which will help you see the common mistakes made by people who call themselves "jQuery developers" and not make them yourself.